# Rotating domain with realistic fluid

Tags: keyframes, baking, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to demonstrate a spray paint can tilting on its side through Blender. I've watched various tutorials and am starting to understand the domain, obstacle, and fluid types so I'm able to simulate a fluid splattering .

I also have figured out how to use keyframes with rotate to slightly tilt the inside of the spray can. In the last keyframe, I tilt the can and the domain.

In the last frame of the liquid's bake, it is splattered but it is not obeying gravity. It's splattered on the bottom of the can although its sideways, when it should be on the sides of the can. I rebaked after the keyframing, but still nothing. I'm assuming it has something to do with the World settings?

I think videos which could point me in the direction to do something similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xl2Ub-v-GuE) would help.